# How to make a relative frequency normal distribution?

Tags: r, histogram, normal-distribution

Ok so basically I have to plot a relative frequency histogram (which I've done) but I also have to plot a normal distribution curve over it. And no matter how I do it it's always for absolute frequency and not relative freqency.

This is what I have so far:

```
set.seed(1099)

N <- 1520
n_1 <- 4
n_2 <- 30
n_3 <- 76
Valor_esperado = (8 + 12)/2
Variancia = (12-8)^2/12

Amostra_1 <- matrix( runif(N*n_1,min = 8,max = 12)
             , nrow = n_1)

Amostra_2 <- matrix( runif(N*n_2,min = 8,max = 12)
, nrow = n_2)

Amostra_3 <- matrix( runif(N*n_3,min = 8,max = 12)
, nrow = n_3)


media_1 <- colMeans(Amostra_1)
media_2 <- colMeans(Amostra_2)
media_3 <- colMeans(Amostra_3)


Amostra_1 <- as.numeric(unlist(media_1))
Amostra_2 <- as.numeric(unlist(media_2))
Amostra_3 <- as.numeric(unlist(media_3))

#par(mfrow=c(2,2))

h <- hist(Amostra_1, plot=FALSE)
h$density = h$counts/sum(h$counts) * 100
plot(h, main="n = 4",
     xlab = NULL,
     ylab="Frequência Relativa",
     col="blue",
     freq=FALSE)


h <- hist(Amostra_2, plot=FALSE)
h$density = h$counts/sum(h$counts) * 100
plot(h, main="n = 30",
     xlab = NULL,
     ylab="Frequência Relativa",
     col="red",
     freq=FALSE)

h <- hist(Amostra_3, plot=FALSE)
h$density = h$counts/sum(h$counts) * 100
plot(h, main="n = 76",
     xlab = NULL,
     ylab="Frequência Relativa",
     col="yellow",
     freq=FALSE)
```

Comment: You could make this example considerably more minimal, for the purposes of explanation (i.e. just show us one relative histogram, for one set of random data, skip all the extra prettiness [setting colour, xlab, ylab, main, etc.])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the histogram you've defined, you need a Gaussian curve that integrates to (100*binwidth) rather than 1. This should do it (for example):

```r
binwidth <- diff(h$breaks)[1]
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(Amostra_1), 
            sd = sd(Amostra_1)) * binwidth*100, 
      add = TRUE)
```

In this particular case the top of the curve gets clipped because the y-axis for the histogram is only based on the bar heights (bin densities), not considering the peak of the theoretical curve. The simple/crude way to fix this would be to add `ylim = c(0, max(h$density)*1.1)` when plotting your histogram, to extend the maximum a bit (one "correct", slightly more annoying way is to compute `max(h$density)`, compute `dnorm(0, ...)*binwidth*100` (the max value of the theoretical curve), and use the maximum of these two values when setting `ylim`).